# 98 Toyota 4Runner headlights turning on without truck on

Tags: toyota, headlight, 4runner

My headlights are turning on randomly after I turn the engine off and the keys are out of the ignition.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Problems like this tend to be water related. Water gets into a fuse box or wiring harness and the head lights are the symptom. Another possible cause is if the truck has automatic head lights, that is they come on automatically when it gets dark. A malfunction in that system can also cause the head lights to come on.

Comment: It's a 98 so manual lights, and it didn't rain all day, any other ideas? How about a relay?

Comment: Unfortunately with the information given there is not a whole lot more to go on. You say that the head lights came on all by themselves. Something has to happen for this to occur, some kind of trigger. As i mentioned water is a very common trigger. Wires get wet, short together, lights come on. You suggest relay, but there is nothing special or magical about a relay. They don't just turn on on their own. From here it really could be anything, burn or melted wiring, crushed wiring harness, squirrels ate the wiring, water intrusion into a connector from driving though a puddle....